# How to send hashmap with a file in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I want to know or some code sample which will help me to **send the file and the hashmap to the server.**

**to upload a file to GWt server i use formpanel and a HttpServlet.
this is working fine.**

i have a hashmap

```
    private static Map<String, List<Customproperties>> docClass =
 new HashMap<String, List<Customproperties>>();
```

which holds the property of document according to its classname.

I know how to do with RPC. but i want to do with servlet.As i have to upload a file which i have done with servlet. And every Hashmap is related to file .and this file with its property(in HashMap) will send to external repository.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried converting the hashmap to a JSON string and sending it to your servlet. Once you servlet gets the JSON string you can convert it back into a Hashmap. There are some nice java JSON libs out there.

Comment: @george_h  : Can u Plz tell how to convert hashMap to string or any link to understand this.

Comment: Ok there are 2 ways to convert a hashmap to a string (and convert it back to a hashmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to convert a hashmap to a string (and convert it back to a hashmap)

1: Convert it using JSON library http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ This will allow you to convert any java object to a JSON string so you can transfer it anywhere. And using the same library or another JSON library, can convert it back to a Java object.

2: Convert it to an XML string using a library called XStream http://x-stream.github.io/ This will convert any Java object into a String represented as XML.

I would recommend to convert your Objects to JSON strings because you are using GWT and it has a lot of support for JSON. And JSON is a good format for Webapps. Another advantage is that other languages can convert your JSON string into an object too.